# Solving a set differential equations for a particle acted on by an inverse-square central force

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following system of equations to find the position and velocity as a function of time:

[image: system of equations]

Now I want to solve it in such a way that I get the answer in terms of t as well as in terms of initial conditions. So I wrote the following code for it:

```
sol = 
  DSolve[
    {vx'[t] == -G M x[t]/R^3, x'[t] == vx[t], 
     vy'[t] == -G M y[t]/R^3, y'[t] == vy[t], 
     vz'[t] == -G M z[t]/R^3, z'[t] == vz[t], 
     x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0, 
     vx[0] == vx0, vy[0] == vy0, vz[0] == vz0}, 
    {vx, vy, vz, x, y, z}, t];
```

I'm getting an error message

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of vx[t] in the first
>   argument.

I don't see any problem with the logic. Can someone help, please?

Comment: You used `=` instead of `==` in `x'[t] = vx[t]` and others. Check your equations, replace all `=`, with `==`, and try again in a fresh kernel.

Comment: I have made those edits, but I'm still getting errors

Comment: Did you try again in a fresh kernel (that is, the line number when you evaluate that should be `In[1]`)?

Comment: Yes. But what @Nasser suggested works. Thanks

Comment: As now corrected, the equations are readily solved by `DSolve`, so I am voting to close this question as caused by simple syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many syntax errors. But it is best to first write the ODE's on their own, then use them in the `DSolve` commands. You are using `=` where `==` is needed. Also in initializations.  And it is not good idea to use single UpperCase letter for variables, it can conflict with Mathematica symbols. I normally add a digit to the letter if I want to use UpperCase single variable, as in `D0` instead of `D` and so on.

```
eq1=vx'[t]==-G M x[t]/R^3;
eq2=x'[t]==vx[t];
eq3=vy'[t]==-G M y[t]/R^3;
eq4=y'[t]==vy[t];
eq5=vz'[t]==-G M z[t]/R^3;
eq6=z'[t]==vz[t];
```

Now set up the IC

```
ic={x[0]==x0,y[0]==y0,z[0]==z0,vx[0]==vx0,vy[0]==vy0,vz[0]==vz0};
```

And only now do

```
sol=DSolve[{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,ic},
      {vx[t],vy[t],vz[t],x[t],y[t],z[t]},t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If I replace R with Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] (which is the actual equation, I'm approximating it to R), DSolve is not working. What else can I do? Can mathematica not solve it symbolically anymore?

Comment: `If I replace R with Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]` first, it should be `Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2]` since these are all functions of time. Second, once you do this, the ODE's become non-linear and `DSolve` is now not able to solve them analytically when I tried it on 11.2. You can use `NDSolve` in this case. But with `NDSolve` you need to have numerical values for the initial conditions.